# Shell Script in post session command to count the target row count

Tags: shell, unix, informatica

I am writing a post session shell script where i have to count the target which is a flat file row count and if the count is greater then 500 then send a mail notifying the same. But there are some errors in the script.

```
DIR="/data/research_dev/inbfiles"
cd /data/research_dev/inbfiles
if [ "$(wc -l ff_invoicepreviewqueue1.csv)" > 500 ]; then
echo "Hi," > InvoicePreview.dat
echo " The row count of InvoicePreviewQueue is:   " >> InvoicePreview.dat
#wc -l ff_invoicepreviewqueue1.csv >> InvoicePreview.dat
echo "                  " >> InvoicePreview.dat
echo "            " >> InvoicePreview.dat
echo "Thanks and Regards," >> InvoicePreview.dat
echo "BI Support team." >> InvoicePreview.dat
mailx -s "Alert!! Count is out of limits!! " "correia.blossom@rexelholdingsusa.com" < InvoicePreview.dat
rm -f InvoicePreview.dat.dat
#
```

Please help me out to find the error

Comment: Hi Marek.. I really dont want to load the data i just want to check count for sysdate -1 and if count is greater than 500 then send an email. So can i do something without loading the data

Comment: I have to implement it in informatica. So i loaded the data in flat file and wrote a script which would count rows in target file but there is error in this script. Informatica session log is not giving full details about the same..

Comment: I have changed the approach.. I am now loading the total count and flag Y or N into a flat file and also passing them to the workflow variable but i am unable to get them at post session script. I am passing it to the script as follows:                                                                                                            sh -x /data/research_dev/scripts/InvoicePreview.sh $$wf_Count $$wf_Count_Flag>/data/research_dev/inbfiles/InvoicePreview.txt

Answer (score 1):

The command `wc -l ff_invoicepreviewqueue1.csv` would usually return count with the file name like, `499 ff_invoicepreviewqueue1.csv`. So you cannot compare it with 500. You may do something like `cat ff_invoicepreviewqueue1.csv|wc -l` which will return only the count.

Also, operator for greater than is "-gt", ">" probably will not work. So to rewrite your if statement it will be:

```
if [ "$(cat ff_invoicepreviewqueue1.csv|wc -l)" -gt 500 ]; then

    # send mail

fi
```

Remember to close the if condition with fi.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it helped..
I loaded the target flatfile from the sql server source and then in assignment task i assigned the workflow variable with source success rows and in decision task if the rows are greater then 500 i called script1 and if the rows are less i called script2

```
 Rows="$(cat /data/research_dev/inbfiles/ff_invoicepreviewqueue.txt|wc -l)"
 echo "Hi," > InvoicePreview.dat
 echo " The row count of InvoicePreviewQueue is:   " >> InvoicePreview.dat
 echo $Rows" Rows">> InvoicePreview.dat
 echo " Please re run the process to correct the count   " >> InvoicePreview.dat
 echo "   " >> InvoicePreview.dat
 echo "                 " >> InvoicePreview.dat
 echo "Thanks and Regards," >> InvoicePreview.dat
 echo "BI Support team." >> InvoicePreview.dat
 mailx -s "Alert!! The count of InvoicePreviewQueue is "$Rows"!! " "correia.blossom@rexelholdingsusa.com" < InvoicePreview.dat
 rm -f InvoicePreview.dat.dat
  #
```

And one more script which executes if the count is less then 500 and sends a mail.
Thank u all for help!